# Splitting Dataframe into multiple parts based on multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, k-means

So I was wondering whether it was possible to sort a dataframe with several rows. For example, lets say there is a dataframe with 5 rows, I want to randomly pick several rows, lets say 2 in this case, which I will designate as centroid1 and centroid2, and then sort the dataframe based on these rows. In this case, the rows less than the centroid1 are above it, the rows that are greater than centroid1 but less than centroid2 are in between them, and the rows greater than centroid2 are below centroid2.

```
def compareRows(arr1, arr2):
    a1 = sum(arr1)
    a2 = sum(arr2)
    return a1 > a2
```

This function is how I compare rows.

```
    data = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/cancer.csv',  header=None))
    data = data.T
    #print(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], dtype=float).T

    sampled = df.sample(1)
    d = df.drop(sampled.index)
    gt = d.apply(compareRows, 1, arr2=sampled.squeeze())
    df = pd.concat([d[~gt], sampled, d[gt]])
```

I understand how to do this with one row. The code above reads in the dataset, and then puts it in a dataframe. Afterwards it takes one sample from the frame, removes it, and then applies the compareRows function to compare whether the other rows are greater or less than it and appends them in the correct location. My question is whether it is possible to generalize this procedure so that it can be done with 1,2,3...n rows. So if I picked 3 centers, it would be similar to my example above with 2 centers, but there would be another center to partition the data.

Any advice is appreciated. Please let me know if require any further information or explanation regarding the issue.

Thank you for reading

Comment: just loop over the last three lines of code, applying a different sample (centroid) each time

Comment: But wouldn't that just sort the dataframe based on the current centroid? I need it to be so that it is arranged in a way such that if there are two centroids the ones lower are above the first, the ones higher than the first but lower than the second are in between, and the rows greater than the 2nd are under the second. If I did it like that it would just sort it by a single centroid.

Comment: *then sort the dataframe based on these rows* ... how do you sort df by rows? What values of the 78 cols will be used? Usually one sorts by columns.

Comment: Yeah true, but for this case I am trying to make it so that if I choose x number of centroids, then the rows above each centroid are less than it, and the rows below are greater for the x centroids. Sort is probably not that right word, its more trying to rearrange the rows based on the number of centroids chosen. Sorry if I'm not explaining this clearly.

Comment: Anyone else haha?

Comment: As long as you applied the centroids in order, i think it would work fine. if you're applying `n` centroids and `sum(centroid_n) < sum(centroid_n+1)` then all rows above `centroid_n` will also be above `centroid_n+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply compare rows iteratively as long as the samples are already in increasing order of their sum

```
def compareRows(arr1, arr2):
    a1 = sum(arr1)
    a2 = sum(arr2)
    return a1 > a2 

def sort_centroids(samples): #just sorts the samples in increasing order of their sum
    order = [float(i.sum(axis=1)) for i in samples]
    std=sorted(zip(samples,order),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
    return [i[0] for i in std]

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array(pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gsprint23/cpts215/master/progassignments/files/cancer.csv',  header=None))
data = data.T
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0], dtype=float).T

num_centroids = 10

samples = [df.sample(1) for i in range(num_centroids)]
samples = sort_centroids(samples)

for i in range(num_centroids): #loop over centroids one by one
    d = df.drop(samples[i].index)
    gt = d.apply(compareRows, 1, arr2=samples[i].squeeze())
    df = pd.concat([d[~gt], samples[i], d[gt]])
```

sanity check :

```
o=[float(i.sum(axis=1)) for i in samples]
o.reverse()
print(o)
print()
print(df.sum(axis=1))
```